# Show/hide child div on toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When the content is displayed on the second box is placed underneath the box, in the box-container, I want it to be moved to far left, underneath both boxes, if I have multiple boxes, on multiple rows, the content should be placed underneath all boxes from the same row as clicked box, this is what I have so far:

```js
$('.show').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().find('.content').slideToggle();
  $(this).parent().parent().siblings().find('.content').slideUp('fast');
});
```

```css
.site-container {
  max-width: 1200px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 0 50px 20px 0;
}

.box-container {
  width: 250px;
}

.content {
  width: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="site-container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box-container">
      <div class="box">
        <button class="show">show</button>
      </div>
      <div class="content" style="display:none">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-container">
      <div class="box">
        <button class="show">show</button>
      </div>
      <div class="content" style="display:none">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/tonyart/pen/VwwBzbP

Comment: your question is not so clear... please explain clearly....

Comment: On the second box when the content is shown is placed underneath the box, in the box-container, I want it to be moved to far left, underneath both boxes

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$('.show').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().find('.content').slideToggle();
  $(this).parent().parent().siblings().find('.content').slideUp('fast');  });
```

```css
.site-container {
  max-width:1200px;
}
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  position:relative;
}
.box {
  width:auto;
  height:100px;
  border:2px solid red;
  margin:0 50px 20px 0;
}
.box-container {
  width:20%;
}
.content {
  width:1200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
bottom: -10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="site-container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box-container">
      <div class="box">
        <button class="show">show</button>
      </div>
      <div class="content" style="display:none">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-container">
      <div class="box">
        <button class="show">show</button>
      </div>
      <div class="content" style="display:none">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-container">
      <div class="box">
        <button class="show">show</button>
      </div>
      <div class="content" style="display:none">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-container">
      <div class="box">
        <button class="show">show</button>
      </div>
      <div class="content" style="display:none">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-container">
      <div class="box">
        <button class="show">show</button>
      </div>
      <div class="content" style="display:none">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
    </div>
        <div class="box-container">
      <div class="box">
        <button class="show">show</button>
      </div>
      <div class="content" style="display:none">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-container">
      <div class="box">
        <button class="show">show</button>
      </div>
      <div class="content" style="display:none">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-container">
      <div class="box">
        <button class="show">show</button>
      </div>
      <div class="content" style="display:none">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-container">
      <div class="box">
        <button class="show">show</button>
      </div>
      <div class="content" style="display:none">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-container">
      <div class="box">
        <button class="show">show</button>
      </div>
      <div class="content" style="display:none">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-container">
      <div class="box">
        <button class="show">show</button>
      </div>
      <div class="content" style="display:none">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks I tried that, but it's not responsive, if I have like 10 boxes, will not fit on same row, once you have multiple rows of boxes, positioning the content absolute will overlap the next row of boxes, see this:
https://codepen.io/tonyart/pen/VwwBzbP

Comment: No.. try my updated code now... even 100 boxes also it will at the bottom left only..

Comment: Yes, thanks, but I want the content to be placed underneath the same row where the box is clicked